# Service not starting at boot

Tags: ubuntu, services

Im on Ubuntu 12.10. I have a service that runs well when I do `sudo service myservice start/stop`

at installation, I did `sudo update-rc.d myservice defaults` and I see that there are in rc*.d some symlinks S93myservice and K93... pointing to /etc/init.d/myservice

But... after doing reboot I can see that my service is not running (`status`). Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, things worked fine. There was a `exit` in my script that would trigger on a special condition (other program running) at boot and not "long" after.